# Open new window in Chrome Developer Console automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window-object

I'm having trouble opening new windows programmatically in Google Chrome (version 62.0.3202.94).

Go give this a try:

```
function test(){
    console.log("haha");
}
setInterval(test, 1000);
```

... and you'll see a new line of `haha` every second.

When you try this:

```
function test(){
    window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/");
}
setInterval(test, 1000);
```

... you won't see a new page of Stack Overflow opening every second.

However, typing `window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/")` into the developer console and hitting enter **does** open a new page of Stack Overflow.

This is quite annoying because I'm going to automate something. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Your browser will most probably block the opening of the window as it is not  triggered by direct user action ie. clicking a button.

Comment: it is working on jsfiddle

Comment: `window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/");` does open a new tab in here. Is there anything blocking popup?

Comment: @undefined You sure it still works when you automate it?

Comment: Its popup blocker blocking it.

Comment: @iBug the automation worked. However It only opened one tab then then subsequent ones are blocked by chrome. Thats when I saw 'Popup blocked' warning in the address bar. https://imgur.com/tGTZvqD

Answer (score 0):

When you execute javscript in the developer console, chrome consider that the code is executing from the website, and it blocks intrusive popups.

So for example, when i execute following code :

```
[0, 1, 2, 3].forEach(x => window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank"))
```

I get following warning in url bar :
[image]

You must explicitly allow chrome to display popups from the page you are executing your code from